# Routing table with openvpn over an unstable wireless network

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

I'm connected to the Internet via a campus network: IP range is, let's say `10.42.0.0/16` and everything has to go through a proxy server `10.42.0.42`.

I'm sometimes connected to this network via a wireless access point, in a local IP range `192.168.0.0/24`, this wireless router being connected to the campus network.

I'm also using a personal VPN, based on OpenVPN. My VPN IP range is `10.8.0.0/24`.

When I'm connected to this wireless network, my routing table is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
```

And when I start my VPN on this wireless network:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.41       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.41       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.42.0.0       192.168.1.1     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.42.0.42      192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     304    0        0 wlan0
```

As you see, I have configured my VPN so that the campus network is not redirected to `tun0`, so that servers in this private zone remains available.

But here comes the problem: the Wireless being unstable (and I can't do anything about it), I am regularly disconnected and reconnected. During this process, **all entries in the routing table about `wlan0` are flushed,** and my table looks like this afterwards:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    304    0        0 wlan0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.41       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.41       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
127.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
```

And nothing works anymore : **all traffic is redirected to tun0**, which doesn't exists any longer and openVPN cannot reconnect to my server (`No route to host.`). The only workaround I found is manually restarting my OpenVPN client.

Is it possible to stabilize this, and how ?

I'm running on Gentoo Linux, managing my network with Wicd.

Comment: Do you control the server?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I indeed control the OpenVPN server, it is outside of the campus network.

Comment: Do you have any info about OpenVPN in /var/log/daemon.log? In /etc/openvpn/openvpn.log?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae simply things like "cannot connect to server, no route to host." But a friend of mine gave ma an other workaroud, I'll write it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, using Wicd scripts to have it restart OpenVPN when connection to Wireless is re-established.

Simply create an executable script in `/etc/wicd/scripts/postconnect/restart-openvpn.sh` checking the existence of OpenVPN PID file and restarting it if it was already started :

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -f /var/run/openvpn.pid ] && /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try as follows. Add these two lines to your client config file:

```
 route-delay 2
 route-up "/path/to/shell/script.sh"
```

The file *script.sh* (which must be made executable) consists of a single command:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ip route add 10.42.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0
```

The command route-delay forces the following commands to be executed 2 seconds (change this as you best see fit) after all of the routes have been set-up; the following command, every time the routes are brought up, executes a shell script, whose only purpose is to add back the *ad-hoc* route you created.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The problem is, if I got disconnected from wireless (like 10 minutes after I started my VPN), OpenVPN is not automatically restarted, and it doesn't reset routes, it just tries to reconnect to server(and can't, because routes are messed up).